# php extension call_user_function segment fault

Tags: php, php-extension

my code is like the follows:

```
ZEND_FUNCTION(mysql_query1)
{
    zval *args[1];
    MAKE_STD_ZVAL(args[0]);
    ZVAL_STRING(args[0], "hehe", 1); 
    zval *fname = NULL;
    ZVAL_STRING(fname, "print", 0); 

    zval *retval = NULL;

    if (call_user_function(EG(function_table), NULL, fname, retval, 1, args TSRMLS_CC) == SUCCESS) {
    }   
}
```

As i tested , it is cored when executing the `call_user_function`, I just want to invoke the
`print()` function of php in my extension, but why does this cause a segment?

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` is not a function, but a language construct. If you want to print a zval use `zend_print_variable(zval)`.

Alternatively you may also be interested in `PHPWRITE(str, len)` and `php_printf(format, ...)`.

The reason your code segfaults is not related to this: You did not allocate the `fname` zval.